# Getting sorted data from a table in LUA

Tags: lua

I am trying to wrap my head around how tables work in Lua, but it is very confusing.

I am pulling data out of an existing table of strings, with an index number for each string. However the numbers are not consecutive. So my data looks like this:

```
mytable[0] = "the first string"
mytable[5] = "the second string"
mytable[13] = "the third string"
mytable[29] = "the fourth string"
```

I want to take each of these strings, concatenate the index number onto them and output them all into a single new string, like this:

```
"0: the first string\n,
5: the second string\n
13: the third string\n
29: the fourth string"
```

If I access the data using pairs, then I get the items out of order, and it is very important that they remain in order.
If I access the data using ipairs, it doesn't work because there are gaps in the index numbers.

How would I go about getting the data from the table into a string, while keeping it all in order?

Comment: Lua tables are glorified hash tables. If you need the elements sorted, you have to do it yourself. E.g.: push them all into a contiguous array, then use `table.sort`.

Comment: @CássioRenan not quite - they do actually have an array part, which is what `ipairs` traverses, but zero is not part of the array part. In this example it is a hash map however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what Cássio says about creating a new array, or (just in case you are interested on an alternative method) you also could do something like this:

```html
<script src="//github.com/fengari-lua/fengari-web/releases/download/v0.1.4/fengari-web.js"></script>
<script type="application/lua">

local mytable = {}
local myvalues = ""
local mystring = ""

mytable[0] = "the first string"
mytable[5] = "the second string"
mytable[13] = "the third string"
mytable[29] = "the fourth string"

for i = 0, 29 do --or any "reasonable" limit you don't expect to reach, like maybe 99 in this case?
    myvalues = mytable[i] or nil
    if myvalues then
        mystring = mystring .. i .. ": " .. myvalues .. "\n"
    end
end
print(mystring)

</script>
```

Which in this case results in:

```
0: the first string
5: the second string
13: the third string
29: the fourth string
```

But you could easily format the resulting string as you want... A less *canonical* way to do it, but there it is just in case it helps.

EDIT: Added as a Lua "snippet" just for the sake of testing it ()

Comment: Thanks, between this and what @CássioRenan wrote, I was able to come to a solution that works for my project!